# D3 keep line width same when zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following creates two lines with thickness 8:

```
var a = [23,50]
for (b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
var stripe = vis.selectAll("line.stripep")
.data(connections.filter(function(d,i) { return i == a[b];  }))
.enter().append("svg:line")
  .attr("class", "stripe")
  .attr("stroke", function(d) { return "#000000"; })
  .attr("stroke-linecap", 'round')
  .style("stroke-width",  function(d) { return 8; } )
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.station1.longitude); })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.station1.latitude); })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.station2.longitude); })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.station2.latitude); })


}
```

I have the following function for zooming

```
function zoomed() {

vis.selectAll("line.route, line.stripe, line.stripep")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.translate() + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")")
vis.selectAll("line.stripep")
.attr("stroke-width", 8 / (zoom.scale()))
```

}

However the line thickness does not change, what is the problem.

I also tried:

```
vis.selectAll("line.stripep")
.style("stroke-width", 8 / (zoom.scale()))
```

Comment: set vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" on the line then you won't need to adjust it at all.

Answer (score 23):

This piece of CSS styling perfectly solves the issue:

```
.line {
    stroke-width: 2px; // desired stroke width (line height)
    vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; // line height won't scale
}
```

No need for additional JS code.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `zoom.scale()` use `d3.event.scale();`

Here is an example I have implemented : http://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/aVhd8/565/1/

Here is the zoom function :

```
function zoomed() {
          container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
          link.style("stroke-width", 8/d3.event.scale);
        }
```

In your case it will be :

```
 vis.selectAll("line.stripep").style("stroke-width", 8/d3.event.scale);
```

Comment: updated answer. I changed my username so it made the old link useless :)

Comment: the question is how do I do it for just the two lines mentioned? I believe the above method does it for all the lines that exist?

Comment: Just dont use link and filter them like you have in the question. Updated answer

Comment: Check this link out http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/aVhd8/566/ I have edited it so it only keeps one line the same width. Zoom in on one of the red lines. @user3809938